# NAND2Tetris Hack

Tags: assembly, nand2tetris

How do I skip 2 commands in hack if I don't know the exact line no. of which the code I want to jump to.

eg.

```
30.@33
31.D;JGT
32.M=M-1
33.M=M+1
```

But I don't know the line no. I am currently at(30), I just want to skip the next line of code(Go 2 steps forward instead of 1) if D;JGT is fulfilled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a symbolic label:

```
    @your_label
    D;JGT
    M=M+1
    M=M+1

(your_label)
```

The assembler will figure out the address of your_label and insert it into the @-op. You don't need to keep track of what instruction address you are at.

Comment: Thanks really helped